# AWS S3 Lambda that copies the most recent file with specific string to another folder in same region via Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am relatively new to the Lambda/Python combo and have the following requirement:

**Use Case**

The following files are located in a subfolder of a S3 bucket.

```
Database1_backup_2021_09_12_024504_9089261.bak
Database2_backup_2021_09_12_024504_9089261.bak
Database3_backup_2021_09_12_024504_9089261.bak
Database4_backup_2021_09_12_024504_9089261.bak
Database5_backup_2021_09_12_024504_9089261.bak
Database1_backup_2020_09_12_024504_9089261.bak
Database2_backup_2020_09_12_024504_9089261.bak
Database3_backup_2020_09_12_024504_9089261.bak
Database4_backup_2020_09_12_024504_9089261.bak
Database5_backup_2020_09_12_024504_9089261.bak
```

I want to only copy the most recent 'Database5' to another subfolder under the same bucket as the source. For example, the destination will need to trim timestamp in the filename such as the following:
Database5_backup.bak

Any guidance on a Lambda python function that will satisfy this requirement? Most of the same scripts that I have found only cover copying all contents of folder or do not copy only one of many files.

Note: I am also investigating where S3 replication could be a better solution for this use case.

Comment: Replication would probably be a better solution to your problem.  You can replicate on a prefix, which does not have to end on a `/` delimiter (remember that folders are not a fundamental part of object storage, and the slash really has no significance.)  If you needed a lambda for additional mutations on the data or something, you might want it to be event based (fire the lambda when a backup is written) rather than scheduled ("last" backup)

Comment: Sorry, but your requirements are unclear. Are you saying that 'something' will trigger an AWS Lambda function, and it should look in a particular sub-folder in S3 and find the **most recent file** (ignoring the name) in that directory and copy it to a different location?

Comment: Thank you all for the swift responses! The requirement is to search the S3 bucket (on particular weekdays). It will need to only pull a particular file name (based on text string in the name) and the most recent revision of that file. My starting point has been the following code but it would be cleaner if S3 replication can handle this one?

Comment: import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'];
    service_name='s3'
    region_name='us-east-2'
    aws_access_key_id=''
    aws_secret_access_key=''
    s3 = boto3.resource(
        service_name=service_name,
        region_name=region_name,
        aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
        aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key
        )
    copy_source = {
        'Bucket': 'demoshow',
        'Key': file_name
    }
    s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'destinationfoldera',file_name)